# Create web socket streams between a server and arbitrary NodeJS processes

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io, server

Having a server running on `localhost:5000`, I want to connect to that server from another NodeJS process, via web sockets.

From my experience with web sockets, I always needed the server object to create a web socket server.

```
var http = require('http');

// create http server
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
   // serve files and responses
   ...
});

// Socket.io server listens to our app
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

// Send current time to all connected clients
function sendTime() {
    io.sockets.emit('time', { time: new Date().toJSON() });
}

// Send current time every 10 secs
setInterval(sendTime, 10000);

// Emit welcome message on connection
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit('welcome', { message: 'Welcome!' });
    socket.on('i am client', console.log);
});

server.listen(3000);
```

This is a tiny example using `socket.io`. Without having access to get the `server` variable (since this server will be deployed some where in the cloud), how can I connect via web sockets to this server?

An ugly solution would be via HTTP requests, but that's not web sockets. I want to keep the connection open and pipe data there.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the `socket.io-client` module, `require()` it into your other nodejs server and use that client module from your other server (which will be the client in this case) and connect from that server to this one.

Example code here: https://github.com/automattic/socket.io-client

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost');
socket.on('connect', function(){});
socket.on('event', function(data){});
socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
```

Comment: That's awesome! I see a whole new world with this feature! Thank you a lot!